# How to select the first row from a query into a procedure-variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE topScorer INT default 0;

SELECT id INTO topScorer FROM game_player
WHERE game_player.score = (SELECT max(score) FROM game_player)
```

A bad example but one that could easily result from naive coding... it doesn't work in my testing if multiple rows are returned, how can I get the first returned row into the variable?

Comment: maybe add "LIMIT 1" to select statement? ;o)

Comment: never seen that keyword before, neat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need just the one score?

```
SELECT id 
  INTO topScorer 
  FROM game_player
 WHERE game_player.score = (   SELECT max(score) as maxScore 
                                 FROM game_player 
                                 ) LIMIT 1
```

Update:
Sir Rufo was right, the code above has now been corrected.

Comment: `SELECT max( Column ) FROM table` will return one or none row. `LIMIT` this statement is useless

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT x` to ensure you are receiving only `x` rows from your query.

In this case you only want to get `1` row:

```
SELECT id 
  INTO topScorer 
  FROM game_player
 WHERE game_player.score = ( SELECT max(score) 
                               FROM game_player )
 LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e51a0/6)

As a working alternative you can also use this

```
  SELECT id 
    INTO topScorer 
    FROM game_player
ORDER BY score DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e51a0/8)

Answer (score 1):

Apply limit in sub query to get only 1 value from sub query

```
SELECT id 
  INTO topScorer 
  FROM game_player
 WHERE game_player.score = ( SELECT max(score) 
                               FROM game_player  LIMIT 1 );
```

Or to get multiple value from sub query used below one:

```
SELECT id 
  INTO topScorer 
  FROM game_player
 WHERE game_player.score in ( SELECT max(score) 
                               FROM game_player );
```

Comment: why do you limit a statement which can only return one or none row as "SELECT MAX( Column ) FROM Table" will do? And "SELECT ... INTO ..." should only return 1 row max, otherwise you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

1) declare variable in SP:

```
declare @CourseID int 
set @CourseID = 0
```

2) We need two query first for assign ID to variable and inner query for select only Top 1 record form table. In where clause of first query we compare ID with result of inner query:

```
SELECT @CourseID = ID FROM Course ID = ( Select Top 1 ID from Course )
```

3) Now check Variable value:

```
 if(@CourseID > 0 )
    Begin
           //This mean ID of first row is assigned to CourseID
    End
    Else 
    Begin
      //Can't found any record.
    End
```